# jq - print "-" for null values

Tags: json, jq

input json:

```
{
  "id": "3885",
  "login": "050111",
  "lastLoginTime": 1529730115000,
  "lastLoginFrom": "192.168.66.230"
}
{
  "id": "3898",
  "login": "050112",
  "lastLoginTime": null,
  "lastLoginFrom": null
}
```

I want to get output for login, lastLoginTime and lastLoginFrom in tabulator delimited format:

```
050111  1529730115000   192.168.66.230
050112              -                -
```

with below jq filter I get on output no "null" values which I could replace with "-"

```
$ jq -r '.|[.login, .lastLoginTime, .lastLoginFrom]|@tsv' test_json
050111  1529730115000   192.168.66.230
050112
```

Is there any other way to get "-" printed for such null values?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

use the [alternative operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#alternative-operator): **//**

so :

```
$jq -r '.|[.login, .lastLoginTime // "-" , .lastLoginFrom // "-" ]|@tsv' test_json
050111  1529730115000   192.168.66.230
050112  -   -
```

Comment: The initial `.|` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is using the same actual feature of `jq` to change the `null` values into dashes as EchoMike444 in [their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451482/116858), but doing it in another way.

Instead of listing the keys to extract, I delete the `id` key that we don't want to use. I then extract the remaining values and use `map()` to change the values that are `null` into dashes:

```bash
$ jq -r '[del(.id)[]] | map(.//"-") | @tsv' file
050111  1529730115000   192.168.66.230
050112  -       -
```

---

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to read the JSON input and change all fields that are null to `-`. We then exclude the `id` field and output what's left as TSV.

```bash
$ mlr --ijson --otsv --headerless-csv-output put 'for (k,v in $*) { is_null(v) { $[k] = "-" } }' then  cut -x -f id file
050111  1529730115000   192.168.66.230
050112  -       -
```

Comment: I also adds, that in complex expressions parenthesis are needed (`(.lastLoginTime // "-")`)